# Track how many times a record has been added

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rail/angular app where users can add movies to their watchlist. I also have suggestion list, this list has all the movie objects for all users to see. Currently I'm trying to add some orderBy functionality into it. I can order on release_date, and created_at but I would like to add the option of ordering on popularity (so how many times a movie has been added) but I'm lost in how to track this data.

This is the create function in my movie_controller,

```
def create
   @movie = Movie.find_or_create_by movie_params
   @movie.trailers.build(params[:trailer])
   current_user.movies << @movie
   redirect_to :root
   current_user.followers.each { |follower| @movie.create_activity(key: 'movie.create', owner: current_user, recipient: follower) }
end
```

To my knowledge (and what I see) is that when a movie that already exists in my database it doesn't get duplicated, but a link between the current_user and the movie is created.

I'm also using a join model to create a link between users and movies, althought I'm unsure the info is needed in this case,

movie model,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

user model,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create `added_count`(any name you want) column in Movie model

Second, define after_add callback

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :movies, after_add: :increment_movie_added_count

def increment_movie_added_count(movie)
  movie.increment(:added_count)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've added the suggested code in my user model, but when I add a movie the `added_count` the value doesn't change.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Could you try to read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html after_add callback

Answer (score 0):

Using `has_many_through` is recommended over `has_and_belongs_to_many`. The Rails docs themselves advise you to use `has_many through` over `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and this makes things easier.

If you do that, you can add a [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching) and let Rails handle the rest.

```
class Movie
  has_many :movie_adds
  has_many :users, through: :movie_adds
end
class User
  has_many :movie_adds
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_ads
end
class MovieAdd
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
end
```

The add the column:

```
add_column :movies, :movie_adds_count, :integer, default: 0
```

Finally, add a scope to order by popularity:

```
class Movie
  # ...
  scope :popular, -> { order(movie_adds_count: :desc) }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but what is `MovieAdd` in the suggestion?